# equivalent MongoDB statement?

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, mongodb, mongoose

I'm new to MongoDB and I wonder how to build the equivalent to the following SQL statement:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE CONCAT(firstName, ' ', lastName) LIKE CONCAT('Walter Whi', '%')
```

Comment: seems like, that mongos text search is what I'm searching for..

Answer (score 0):

You can find like this example

```
db.users.insert({name: 'paulo'})
db.users.insert({name: 'patric'})
db.users.insert({name: 'pedro'})

db.users.find({name: /a/})  //like '%a%' out: paulo, patric
db.users.find({name: /^pa/}) //like 'pa%' out: paulo, patric
db.users.find({name: /ro$/}) //like '%ro'
db.students.aggregate(      
 { $project: {studentNo:"$studentNo" , name: { $concat: [ "$firstName", " ", "$lastName" ] },age:"$age"}},
  {$match:{ "name":/Suraj/}})
```

project is used to list down all the columns plus concat two columns and then search on  new records

Aggregation is a way in MongoDB to where we can add clauses like where, having in SQL.

For more understanding, you can learn from 
click [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/)

Answer (score 0):

CONCAT in SQL is equaled to the aggregate method in MongoDB.
Tables in SQL is equaled to the documents in MongoDB.
SELECT in SQL is equaled to the Projection method in MongoDB.

> db.users.aggregate(    [
>         { $project: { userDescription: { $concat: [ "$firstName", " - ", "$lastName" ] } } },
>         { $match : { $firstName: "Walter Whi" } }    ] )

Please refer this document for further details.
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/